# Stylesheet delayed on firefox

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, firefox

My asp.net MVC application use bundling to render stylesheet in my _Layout Page. Once my application deployed, I use Firefox and navigate to my login page and got this weird behavior I can't explain.

When I clear firefox cache to force reload stylesheet from server, I first see my page without any style applied. Then once the stylesheet is loaded, style are applied wich cause some unwanted 'flickering'. On chrome an IE, nothing is displayed before stylesheets are loaded, so no flickering here. I also have a really similar web app on my server for which, when I browse it with firefox, the 'flickering' problem doesn't occur. So I guess it must be something, maybe the order of code blocks in my page, that causes this behavior, not only the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a place where whe can look into your code? It's kinda hard to give an answer by just this question and information. The problem can be caused by alot of possibilities.

Did you try viewing the application on another computer? Sometimes that can be handy to determine if the issue is local (or is a general issue).

If there is a link to share, that would be great.